# VMware and Ansible - Resource pools?

Tags: vmware, ansible

I'm currently attempting to write a playbook to deploy virtual machines in our VMware cluster, and I'm currently at a loss. No matter what is being input into the playbook, it will not recognize the resource pool.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  user: remote
  sudo: false

  vars_prompt
    - name: "resource_pool"
      prompt: "Enter resource pool"
      private: no

  vars:
    notes: 'Created by Ansible'
    vcenter_hostname: 'esxhost.local'
    vcenter_username: 'om'
    vcenter_password: '*********'

  tasks:
    - vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        guest: "{{ vm_name }}"
        cluster: DummyCluster
        resource_pool: "{{ resource_pool }}"
        from_template: no
        template_src: testvm001
        vm_extra_config:
          notes: "{{ notes }}"
        vm_disk:
          disk1:
            size_gb: 10
            type: thin
            datastore: dummystore01
        vm_nic:
          nic1:
            type: vmxnet3
            network: vlan48-internal
            network_type: standard
        vm_hardware:
          memory_mb: 512
          num_cpus: 1
          osid: ubuntu64Guest
          scsi: paravirtual
        esxi:
          datacenter: DUMMY-DC
          hostname: esxdummy01.local
```

No matter how I define the resource pool, it always returns an error. In the official documentation, resource pools are shown off as being defined:

```
resource_pool: "/Resources"
```

Where `"/Resources"`, I assume is the resource pool, though this, with or without front slash, will not work.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Does Ansible error? Or does it run through without error but doesn't do what you are expecting? If it errors can you display the error? Also, have you tried hardcoding the resource_pool variable in the task? What's the result of that?

Comment: Ansible returns an error that it does not find the resource pool and aborts the playbook job. Hardcoding the value as described in the documentation retursn the same result, Ansible being unable to find the resource group in the DC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my solution in a question on ServerFault. Turns out the way you need to define the resource pool is using /Resources as a kind of directory.

So to add a machine to the resource pool named 'TestVM', you would need to define the following:

```
resource_pool: "/Resources/TestVM"
```

Hope this helps anyone that's been in my boat.